# Forth local variable assigning variables

Tags: forth, gforth

I have a simple local variable in Forth:

```
: subtraction { a b } a b - ;
```

I would like to assign the output of

```
a b -
```

to another variable, say c.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TO` works for both `VALUE`s and local variables, so:

```
: subtraction { a b | c -- } a b - to c ;
```

Comment: Do you have to have the | c — part? Can c just be a variable within the local variable. I’m thinking of it as being inside a function and declaring a new variable like in Java.

Comment: Yes, you do.  This declares a and b to be local variables that take their values off the stack, and c to be an uninitialized local variable.